# Modeling event or message in a event / message driven architecture

Tags: design-patterns, microservices, event-driven

I'm modeling messages to be used in an integration among microservices. Did You ever seen a design pattern  specific for messages?

For example, in message bellow , how could I represent if child with ID F123 was deleted?

There's a little trap, because I could send delete event from entity Son but in this case I just want kill the relationship between entity Father x entity Son. So, My event is an update in entity Father to delete the relationship with entity Son.

The consumer could do a diff between message and local data, but comparing every message with high data volumes could be very expensive.

```
{
   "header":{
      "op":"updated_father"
   },
   "body":{
      "id":"1234",
      "entity_type":"father",
      "childs":[
         {
            "child":{
               "id":"f123",
               "entity_type":"son"
            }
         },
         {
            "child":{
               "id":"f333",
               "entity_type":"son"
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

One of the great things about event messages: you are not forced to stick to the CRUD verbs.

An event message is a description of something interesting which has happened in the past. For that reason, events can be modelled at as fine a grain as is necessary, and the event name should have business meaning. What do we mean by *business meaning*?

An event has business meaning if it describes something that happens in a real business setting. Examples of event names with business meaning:

- Invoice raised
- Stock exhausted
- Contract signed
- Customer upgraded

When someone from the business can understand the meaning of your event names, then your events have business meaning. On the flip side, if someone from the business would be confused by your event names, you know that your events only have technical meaning.

In this light, your current event name *updated_father* doesn't really have any business meaning. Why was this record updated? There could be 10 different business reasons to update this record. Which one was it?

In the same way, a change to a technical relationship between two records (parent-child in your example) just becomes a new type of event, based on the actual business reason that causes the event to be generated.

The goal of writing this answer was to try to give you a new way to think about events, which will hopefully free you from the constraints of CRUD.